# libcurl: how to get a file descriptor from an active connection?

Tags: libcurl

Piggybacking on the topic described here ([Using libcurl multi interface for consecutive requests for same "easy" handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483937/using-libcurl-multi-interface-for-consecutive-requests-for-same-easy-handle)), my organization has wrapper classes for select and poll to handle input/output from file descriptors.  In keeping aligned with our wrapper classes, I would like to get the file descriptor of each easy handle.  I'm using the multi interface to work with multiple easy handles in a real time application.

I understand I can use the curl_multi_fd_set to get the FD sets.  I could loop through the FD set to get the FD number.  However, I won't know the associated easy handle for the FD.  Additionally, if an FD is opened above the FD_SET limit, I won't get that FD.

Another option I'm considering is to use the curl_easy_getinfo and use the ACTIVESOCKET or LASTSOCKET options.  My libcurl is old, so I couldn't use the ACTIVESOCKET for a test.  However, a little test I performed using the curl_multi_perform, followed by a curl_easy_getinfo(LASTSOCKET) gave me a result of -1 -- meaning no file descriptor.  Easy handle requests were performed on websites such as google.com.  I'll try to update my libcurl to a newer version to see if I get a different result with the ACTIVESOCKET.

Is there another way to get the file descriptor from the easy handle?

Answer (score 1):

I would propose you switch over and use the [multi_socket API](https://ec.haxx.se/libcurl-drive-multi-socket.html) instead, with [curl_multi_socket_action](https://ec.haxx.se/libcurl-drive-multi-socket.html) being the primary driver.

This API calls you to tell you about each and every socket to wait for, and then you wait for that/those and tell libcurl when something happened on that socket. It allows you to incorporate libcurl into your own IO loop/socket wrapper systems pretty easily.